# how to setup noindex,follow in a static page in magento2?

Tags: magento2, seo, cms-pages, index

I would set the robots meta tags to "noindex,follow" in a static page.

For Magento 1.9 I used to do it like this:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

How to do it in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it admin. for magento.
For Magento 2.1 & 2.2 Go to Content > Configuration. please edit your theme .you can see your screen as attached screen shot. i have highlighted seo robots section. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP1Si.png

For Magento 2.0 you can check here :
https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/magento-2-robots/

Answer (score 0):

In **your_layout_handle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you try ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
      <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/>
      </head>
     </layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing go to admin and find Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> Search Engine Robots -> Default Robots (Select) Here you can set the robots meta tags to "noindex,follow".

For particular page or handle you can use XML.