# Magento 2 | Add NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW to CMS page using Layout Update XML

Tags: magento2, xml

How do I add the following robots META tag to a CMS page in Magento 2 using the Layout Update XML field?

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
```

I have tried the suggestions in the following questions, but none of them work

- [how to setup noindex,follow in a static page in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/how-to-setup-noindex-follow-in-a-static-page-in-magento2)
- [NO INDEX, NO FOLLOW on Specific Category Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162381/no-index-no-follow-on-specific-category-magento-2)
- [How can I add meta noindex to all catalog search result pages in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119901/how-can-i-add-meta-noindex-to-all-catalog-search-result-pages-in-magento2)

For example when I add the following code to the Layout Update XML field:

```
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
```

I get this error

> Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'head': This element is 
>    not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, 
>    move ). Line: 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in Magento.  You should be able to update HEAD tags or specifically the robots META tags using XML in the Layout Update XML field.

Here is a link to the issue on Github with the solution. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4454

After `vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd` has been fixed you should be able to use

```
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
```

or

```
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/>
</head>
```

in the Layout Update XML field of the page in order to update the robots META tag.

Comment: I see you found a solution. Sorry to have left you hanging, I left for vacation before I could answer your new question. But glad to see you figured it out and taught me something that I should have known but didnt :-)

Comment: No worries Shawn, thanks for the assist.  Your targeting solution will helpful for other needs.

Answer (score 8):

To set the robots to NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW for a specific CMS page with a URL key of `no-route-2`, I usually create 2 files. Yes, this can be done in one file but I usually find that there is more than one page that I want to set the robots for and I don't like repetitive code. I'll show you both ways.

Create file **Magento_Theme/layout/noindex_nofollow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Create file **Magento_Theme/layout/cms_page_view_id_no-route-2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="noindex_nofollow" />
</page>
```

After this, flush the cache and refresh the page and your robots for that one specific page will be updated. For any additional pages, just create duplicate the cms_page_view_id_no-route-2.xml file contents but be sure to name the new file appropriate to match the next page you are doing this for.

I should also mention, that you probably want to set this page's robots to NOINDEX,FOLLOW. That is because you dont want to index the page but you should want the search engines to continue crawling your site, assuming that the page contains mostly internal links.

In that case, you would do:

Create file **Magento_Theme/layout/noindex_follow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Create file **Magento_Theme/layout/cms_page_view_id_no-route-2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="noindex_follow" />
</page>
```

---

The way to do this in one file for one specific page is:

Create file **Magento_Theme/layout/cms_page_view_id_no-route-2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, can I paste that entire snippet in the  Layout Update XML field for the CMS page I am trying to update?  Or do I have to create a dedicated `Magento_Theme/layout/noindex_nofollow.xml` layout file in order for it to work?

Comment: When I try to paste the entire snippet I get an error `Please correct the XML data and try again. XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document Line: 1`

Comment: Ah yes, this snippet is intented to live in a file within your theme. Unfortunately, in M2, I have not had much success setting robots by pasting the content into the "Layout Update XML" section. It worked in M1 but in M2 it still does not.

Comment: Btw, as long as you have access to your file system, you can still target a specific page, you just need to determine the layout handle for the specific page.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I am still unable to get it to work. I created the file `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/noindex_nofollow.xml` with the XML snippet you provided.  On my CMS page I inserted `<update handle="noindex_nofollow" />` and was able to save it successfully. Then I cleared my cache.  But the page on the frontend still has the default `<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>` meta tag. Is there something obvious that I am overlooking?

Comment: Yes, even though update handle is allowed in the CMS page block, it does not work there. I think this is a core bug. However, if you know the specific layout handle for your page, you can create a second file for it. I will try to update my answer with an example of what I mean as I use this all the time.

Comment: Btw, what is the identifier for your CMS page? I want to see if I can give you an example specific to your scenario that you could just drop right in.

Comment: The URL key for my page is `no-route-2` Thanks Shawn!

Comment: Ill take a look at this right now.

Comment: @EpixRu detailed answer is now posted with and you can drop this right into your site.

Comment: Thank You @shawn-abramson!  This is awesome & it worked just as you described.  Your right about NOINDEX,FOLLOW that is the better option to use.  Thanks for showing how to target a specific page in one file, that will be good to know in the future.

Comment: But I must admit that it didn't work at first and there is one caveat to this solution.  This targeted layout update only works if the URL matches the URL key of the page, such as `https://example.com/no-route-2`  In my particular scenario , the page in question is a 404 page and I was testing your solution with broken URLs ie. `https://example.com/nothinghere` With URLs that don't match the URL key, it doesn't work, even though the page is being served by Magento.  Only when you go to the actual URL of the 404 page it works.

Comment: A fair point. An observer or plugin could fix this. Are you familiar with how to create the basic structure of an extension? If you can do that, I can give you the code needed to make it work no matter what the URL.

Comment: No unfortunately I am not familiar with creating an observer. I have read up on plugins, but haven't created one myself. But I have learned a ton today in regards to layout handles and targeting specific pages with XML updates. I would greatly appreciate it if you could show me the code necessary to make it work on any URL.
But I am wondering if I should perhaps create another question to handle this particular functionality, to make it clear for all future generations. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, actually a new question would be perfect.

Comment: I am not sure if you saw this, but I posted the new question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224676/magento-2-add-noindex-follow-to-404-cms-page-using-xml

Comment: Great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply edit your existing Magento CMS pages to include a snippet to have the noindex and / or nofollow attributes set.

It will use the robots meta tag  to tell the robots what to do.

To edit a page’s properties, simply click on **CMS  -> Pages** , and open the page you would like to edit.

You will now see the page editor. Click on the Design  tab to the left of the editor.

Use the field Layout Update XML  to insert the code you want to use. You can find examples below.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Magento recommends against using "action" in Magento 2. Also, I don't think `reference` is valid as I have never seen it used. As far as I know, you can only use `referenceBlock` or `referenceContainer` in M2.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson , sorry i just edit my code. will you please check it. now it works

Comment: @Divyesh When I used the XML in your post I received an "Element 'page': This element is not expected." error

I removed the page tags and tried again, but received another error "Element 'head': This element is not expected."

Comment: @here - Magento devs who are running with the Magento v2.3.4 or later can find their solution here because XML input field is no longer exists in v2.3.4 or later. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#create-cms-pageproductcategory-specific-layouts