# Magento 2 | Add NOINDEX, FOLLOW to 404 CMS page using XML

Tags: magento2, xml

How do I add `NOINDEX, FOLLOW` robots META tag to a custom 404 CMS page in Magento using XML, no matter what URL the page is served at?

By following the answer on [this page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224522/magento-2-add-noindex-nofollow-to-cms-page-using-layout-update-xml), I was able to figure out how to target a specific Magento CMS Page (using the URL key) and then use a Layout Handle to change the robots META tag to `NOINDEX, FOLLOW`.  Which would work great for a static page.

But my page is meant for 404 errors and is served at many different URLs.  The problem with the solution in the link above is that it only works if the URL matches the URL key of the page. (The URL key of my 404 page is `no-route-2`) So if my 404 page is served at a URL that does not match the URL key ie. `https://example.com/nothinghere`, the  robots META tag will not be updated.

But if you go to `https://example.com/no-route-2` it will work.

I need the  robots META tag of my page to have `NOINDEX, FOLLOW` no matter what URL it is served at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug in Magento.  You should be able to update HEAD tags or specifically the robots META tags using XML in the Layout Update XML field.

Here is a link to the issue on Github with the solution. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4454

After `vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd` has been fixed you should be able to use

```
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
```

or

```
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/>
</head>
```

in the Layout Update XML field of the page in order to update the robots META tag.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, however you can also use XML file name **cms_noroute_index.xml** in your theme and add

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/>
       </head>
    </page>
```