# How to Set ‘No-Index’ & ‘No-Follow’ Tags For Specific Pages in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, seo, page, no-index, no-follow

How can I set a specific page to NO INDEX, NO FOLLOW in Magento 2?

Comment: There is a better way:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224676/magento-2-add-noindex-follow-to-404-cms-page-using-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this answer your issue ? https://www.mag-manager.com/product-information/set-magento-2-noindex-and-nofollow-tags/

You can also handle it yourself with an observer on the following event : `layout_generate_blocks_after`

```
class MetaRobots implements ObserverInterface {

protected $request;

protected $layoutFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $layoutFactory
) {
   $this->request = $request;
   $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
  }



    public function execute(Observer $observer) {

    $fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();

     if ($fullActionName == "catalog_product_view"){
      $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
       }
    }
}
```